# error handling on get_meta_tags() and redirection limits?

Tags: php, error-handling, screen-scraping

I'm using get_meta_tags() in a script and on certain URLs it fails out with (as an example)...

**Warning**:  get_meta_tags(http://www.kodak.com/) [function.get-meta-tags]: failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached...

Is it possible to just skip over any result that throws an error? Or should I just use @get_meta_tags() instead?

```
function getMeta()
{
    $tags = get_meta_tags($this->link); //INSERT INTEGRITY CHECK HERE?
    $keywords = $tags['keywords']; 

    if(count($keywords))
    {
        preg_match_all('/(?<=^|,)\s*((?:[^\s,]+\s*){1,4})(?=\s*(?:,|$))/', $keywords, $m);
        $this->keywords = array_slice($m[1], 0, 15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [error suppression operator - the `@` character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) - directly before the call to `get_meta_tags()`. This has the effect of turning all error reporting off for that line only, but it's generally regarded as a bad practice, only to be used when you other options are all exhausted.

Your first reaction to this should be to try to pass a canonical URL to `get_meta_tags()` where possible - i.e. you should try to pass the URL at the end of the redirection chain: for example, link to `http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php` rather than `http://php.net/array`. If `$this-link` comes from a source out of your control, however, using error suppression might be your best bet:

You can use it as follows:

```
$tags = @get_meta_tags($this->link);
```

This is functionally the same as this:

```
$errorLevel = error_reporting(0);
$tags = get_meta_tags($this->link);
error_reporting($errorLevel);
```

You'll need to change the rest of your code to deal with the `$tags` variable not containing an array of meta tags.

Comment: The links are coming from a screen scrape of google search for a given search query. I don't think its a canonical issue though, the link its chocking on is perfectly fine and well formed (www.kodak.com), no?

Comment: @RegEdit - What I mean by "canonical link" is "the link at the end of the redirection chain". If you go to kodak.com, it could detect your location and redirect to a localized site, which could then be redirected to something else. The canonical link is the URL you'll eventually be shown in your browser when you get to the final page. Basically, I'm telling you to do what you can to limit redirection, to stop the redirection limit from being reached, so that the error is never thrown. If you can't do that, then your next best option is to just silently ignore the error.

Comment: @RegEdit - If you're pulling the URL via screen scraping, there's very little you can do about redirection, so using `@` is probably required. The only other option would be to setup your own error handler via `set_error_handler()` to convert errors to exceptions, then run your `get_meta_tags()` call in a try-catch block with a check in the catch to determine if you've hit the redirection limit. This is pretty much the same as using the error suppression operator, but with the added bonus of only suppressing the error you want to suppress. It's very likely overkill here though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with using error suppressing, but there are a few exceptions it does come in handy.

```
function getMeta()
{
    if ($tags = @get_meta_tags($this->link)) {
        $keywords = $tags['keywords'];

        if (count($keywords)) {
            preg_match_all('/(?<=^|,)\s*((?:[^\s,]+\s*){1,4})(?=\s*(?:,|$))/', $keywords, $m);
            $this->keywords = array_slice($m[1], 0, 15);
        }
    } else {
        // Catch error
    }
}
```

Be warned that the `@` error suppressor will suppress *all* errors, not just exceeded redirect limit. [See docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

This one suppress  all errors, but does exactly thing you're looking for

```
function getMeta()
{
    $tags = @get_meta_tags($this->link); //INSERT INTEGRITY CHECK HERE?
    if (!$tags){
        //handle your error
    }

    $keywords = $tags['keywords']; 

    if(count($keywords))
    {
        preg_match_all('/(?<=^|,)\s*((?:[^\s,]+\s*){1,4})(?=\s*(?:,|$))/', $keywords, $m);
        $this->keywords = array_slice($m[1], 0, 15);
    }
}
```